# I am using telegram bot api using POST method. I am stuck at uploading group media

Tags: javascript, file-upload, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

In the section of telegram `InputMediaDocument` I am not getting how can I upload file using multipart? At what palce should I place the blob of my file? The parameters go as follows:

```
type:String,
media:String,
thunb:Input File/String,
.
.
.
```

and so on...
How can I upload my file at `media` as `String`? In the description it says
`Pass “attach://<file_attach_name>” to upload a new one using multipart/form-data under <file_attach_name> name.` What is the meaning of `<file_attach_name>`?

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I found out that it was very easy!
Structurize your data as:

```
  const data = [
    {type':document,'media':'attach://file1'},
    {type:'document',media:'attach://file2',caption:"This is file 2"},
    {type:'jpg',media:'attach://photo',caption:"This is a photo"},
    {type:'video',media:'attach://video',caption:"This is a Video"}
  ];
  const postData = {
    method: "sendMediaGroup",
    chat_id: String(chat_id),
    media: JSON.stringify(data),
    file1:blob,
    file2:blob1,
    photo:blob3,
    video:blob4
  }
```

Try this and you'll get the results!